# Today, can I safely use CSS Flexbox and Grid in order to develop my Magento theme?

Tags: css

Today (April 2021), can I safely use these new CSS property in order to develop my Magento theme?

- `Flexbox`
- `Grid`

Or should I still prefer `Float` and `Inline-Block`?

This is my audience:

[image]

Comment: Yes you can... Why do you think you can't please let me know that. thanks

Comment: Because, if I understand correctly, many browsers still don't support (or fully support) the Flexbox and Grid properties. E.g. Internet Explorer, and many other browsers in that list. Isn't right? Should I write down my css without any Flex and Grid properties and use something like `@supports (display: grid)` or it isn't necessary?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/CSS_Grid_and_Progressive_Enhancement for grid

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Backwards_Compatibility_of_Flexbox for flexbox

Comment: Or you can do css for small part and check it on all different browser..

Comment: I noticed original Luma theme doesn't use any Flex or Grid layouts. They used `float` and `display: table` all over. Do you know why?